# How to search html using file_get_content() and retrieve a specific DIV class?

Tags: php

Good day.

I want to **file_get_content()** to load a webpage and use strip_tags() to get the string: **Category:Apple**.

```
<div class="category">
    <span style="font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;">Category:</span>
           <a href="/listing/A/new/yp/search.do?applicationInd=A" 
                class="category">Apple
           </a>
</div>
```

eg.

```
$text = '<div class="category">
         <span style="font-size:11px; fontweight:bold;">
         Category:</span><a href="/listing/A/new/yp/search.do?applicationInd=A"
         class="category">Apple</a></div>';

         echo strip_tags($text); //Category:Apple
```

What php statement do I need to do to pass variable to $text for that  **...** ?

Use preg_match?

Comment: What output you expecting ? Your question seems bit unclear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
preg_match('|<a href="([^"]*?)" class="category">([^>]*?)<\/a>|smi', $text, $matches);
$cat = "Category:" . $matches[2];
echo $cat;
```

Comment: I would feel better if you allowed for white space before the 'class' and arbitrary text before the closing '>'. If you really want to be careful, handle white space around the '=' as well, and single, as well as double quotes.

Comment: Don't encourage bad practices! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not Always use a parser kids!

Comment: @Carl I would feel better if regex wasn't used in this case *at all*!